# How to divide standard deviations?

Tags: standard-deviation

I am trying to work out the standard deviation of a percentage change. I have the mean baseline value 'a' and the mean follow up value 'b', along with their standard deviations.

Percentage change is: (b-a)/a

I am able to calculate the SD of (b-a): 
[image]

The formula for which I obtained from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty

However, I am not quite sure how to implement the suggest formula for (b-a)/a asI believe I would need to use this formula:[image]

However I am not sure how to go about this? Do A and B refer to the mean value of A and B? Any advice as to how to input f?

Thanks

Rob

Comment: "This table shows the variances of simple functions of the real variables $A,B$..." The variance/s.d. depend on the values of $A$ and $B$. Similarly, $f$ depends on the ratio.

Comment: Dear Eric - many thanks, so in the example I give would A simply be the mean of (a-b)? and B the mean of 'a'. I am still slightly unclear as to what f would be - would it be (b-a)/a. I had tried that on a test dataset and it did not seem to work. Thanks

Comment: I think what you want to consider is $f = A/B$, since $(A-B)/B = A/B - 1$. $A$ and $B$ are random variables, not expectations. The link doesn't seem to offer specific advice on the estimation of $\sigma_f$. This might be of interest: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution